# iphone automate app installations and interactions

Tags: iphone, automation, installation, app-store

Ok. I'm not sure if this is possible. -

I'm wondering if given a list of iphone applications can an automator be written to install those on an iphone (from the appstore) and probably take a few screenshots too?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think such a thing would be possible, using Xcode.
To use Xcode, you will need to have a mac. You can see the link here for Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Although i seriously doubt if Apple will approve your app.

If it is just for personal use, you can do this trough a developer account, but that aint free either at apple. If i recall correct that would be around 99 dollar/year.